# javascript replace backslashes with forward slashes on path

Tags: javascript

I have a windows path and I'm trying to make backslashes turn into forward slashes which works for the 2 \ after the drive name and the middle slash but the end slash doesn't get changed. I would think the 2nd replace should change both the middle AND last but it doesn't. Any idea why?

```
var test = "D:\\\\Games\\Scrolls\\";

console.log(test.replace("\\\\", "//").replace("\\", "/"));
```

Comment: `.replace("string", "replacement")` only replaces the first occurrence - use `.replace(/regex/g, "replacement")` for multiple replacements

Comment: Man that's going to be nasty  with the /'s needed around it and what I'm changing is slashes :)

Comment: regexp, the gift that keeps on giving :p

Comment: I guess I'll ask a new question with what the regex should be because those things are a pain.

Comment: try yourself first https://regex101.com/